# Concurrency processing in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-integration

I am reading [this article](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/archive/1.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch05.html) running a spring integration cafe sample code. Below is the program flow.

[image: program flow]

I am just curious if the first batch of order comes in with 100 drinks, and at the time the 50th drink is processing in the drink router, then the second batch of order comes in with 200 drinks, does the application know to block the second batch of order before completely process the first batch of order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Spring Integration in a few years, but I think that whether the application blocks Order#2 until Order#1 is complete is based on the type of channels you use. I *think* by default it would block because the example doesn't specify a channel type (thus using a DirectChannel).  The use of a different type of channel could allow `DrinkOrder`s to be processed in a non-blocking way.

From http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html

> In addition to being the simplest point-to-point channel option, one of its most important features is that it enables a single thread to perform the operations on "both sides" of the channel. For example, if a handler is subscribed to a DirectChannel, then sending a Message to that channel will trigger invocation of that handler's handleMessage(Message) method directly in the sender's thread, before the send() method invocation can return.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean with DirectChannel it works in serial mode, but with QueueChannel, i.e. add the `<queue/>` tag, then it becomes parallel mode? Am I wrong or it's really that magical?

Comment: Yes, as far as I remember, DirectChannel is serial, and QueueChannel allows things to be executed in parallel.